# Proper way to evaluate/get status of boolean field when looping through SP List with code

Tags: 2010, web-part, splistitem, splistitemcollection

What is the best way to do this when looping a list? I have tried to evaluate it with something like this but it wont let me evaluate bool as an "if" condition

```
   if (item["ShowTitle"] == true)
//do something
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
 if (bool.Parse(item["ShowTitle"].ToString()) == true)
```

or

```
if (item["ShowTitle"].ToString() == true.ToString())
```

Answer (score 3):

All answers are not safe, when the field is null. This can happen, when a field gets later added and already items are in this list.

This is a safe cast:

```
bool? showTitle = properties.ListItem["ShowTitle"] as bool?;
if (showTitle.HasValue && showTitle.Value)
{

}
```

Comment: I really like your approach and would love to have this the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be the cleanest way of doing it with C#:

```
    if ((bool)item["ShowTitle"] == true)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
```